# Subtract elements from an array and then find number of digits in array

Tags: java

So I'm trying to find the number of digits in an array of integers. The first part is to subtract and find the difference between integer elements in an array and create a new array with those differences. Then I need to subtract and find the difference in digits from the first array and the second array. Here's the code I have so far:

```
public static String compressArray(int[] intArray) {
    int[] finalArray;
    finalArray = new int[intArray.length - 1];
    finalArray [0] = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length - 1; i++) {
        finalArray [i+1] = intArray [i+1] - intArray [i];
    }


}
```

I'm completely unsure of what to do next to find the second part. Basically, start with an array of numbers: 4283, 4296, 4344, 4348, 4355, 4367, 4392, 4391, 4380, then subtract the previous element from the current element and find the differences in them and get a new array: 4283, 13, 48, 4, 8, 12, 25, -1, -11. And then subtract the number of digits in the second array from the number in the first to get: 19.

**I am stuck on how to find the number of digits in the first array and the number of digits in the second, then subtract those two numbers.**

Comment: Your question is confusing. Please rephrase the same. What do you mean by difference?

Comment: @BhushanBhangale edited my post. For the first part (with the code I posted) I need to take the first element and subtract 0. Then the second element I need to subtract it from the first original element. And do that for each and every element, subtracting the current from the previous. And for the second part I need to find the total number of digits in the original array and subtract the total number of digits in the second array.

Comment: so are you stuck on part 1 or 2 ?

Comment: @RenukaDeshmukh I am stuck on part 2, finding the number of digits in the first array and the number in the second array, and then subtracting those numbers.

Comment: so you could iterate on both array, convert the numbers to string and then use an inbuilt function to find the length of string. you will have to be careful with negative numbers. just subtract 1 from such numbers, to account for the - sign. does that work ?

Comment: @malloz16 Take a look at my solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am stuck on how to find the number of digits in the first array and the number of digits in the second, then subtract those two numbers.

To find the number of digits in an integer:

```
int length = String.valueOf(num).length();
```

To find the difference of digits in 2 arrays:

```
int arr1Digits = 0, arr2Digits = 0;
for(int x=0; x<arr1.length; x++)
    arr1Digits += String.valueOf(Math.abs(arr1[x])).length();    //Sum of digits in arr1

for(int x=0; x<arr2.length; x++)
    arr2Digits += String.valueOf(Math.abs(arr2[x])).length();    //Sum of digits in arr2


int diff = arr1Digits - arr2Digits;
```